# Xamarin Forms NavigationPage Icon Sizes

Tags: xamarin, icons, xamarin.forms, size, toolbar

I'm trying to create a navigation bar for my Xamarin Forms app.  I'm adding some primary ToolbarItems which will have an icon associated with them using the following syntax:

```
ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Search", "ic_action_search.png", ActionSearch, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
```

I've searched everywhere but I cannot find the recommended images sizes for each platform (Android, iOS, UWP, Windows, and WinPhone).

Does anyone know what they should be?

Answer (score 3):

A google search for "recommended tool bar icon sizes [Android|iOS|UWP] was very useful here.

iOS:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/

[image: iOS Custom Icon Sizes]

Android:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html

[image: Android Custom Icon Sizes]

UWP:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets

No good chart that I found for UWP as it is quite a bit more complex due to support of Tablets, Phones, and Desktop, but the needed info is in the guide above.

Comment: This is good research and helps me come up with dimensions for my images, but Xamarin Forms uses device pixels to keep dimensions independent of scale.  How do I take the info you have supplied and calculate the device pixels for design time?

Comment: Incidently, the UWP article is all about tile icons and not about navigation bar icons